# nonlinear interpolation question

Tags: interpolation, interpolation-theory

[image: Errata]

Hi all,
here is an screenshot from book called rotation transforms for computer graphics by John Vince. I think here is an error ,if it doesn't please explain how do m+n equals 1 
Thank you

Comment: It is a condition to be satisfied in order to get $\mathbf v$ as a unit vector.

Comment: where I can get more information about that ? or how do we called that transformation thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to my comment.
Draw the line passing through the tip of $\mathbf v$ and parallel to $\mathbf v_2$ and find $\mathbf v$ as the sum of two vectors parallel to $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$ respectively, so $$\mathbf v=a\mathbf v_1 + b\mathbf v_2$$ If $\mathbf v_2$ is separated from $\mathbf v_1$ by $\theta$ and $\mathbf v$ is separated from $\mathbf v_1$ by $\varphi$, the sine law gives $$\frac 1{\sin \theta}=\frac a{\sin(\theta-\varphi)}=\frac b{\sin \varphi}$$ and then $a$ and $b$ .

Search by *spherical interpolation* or *slerp* .

Comment: Thank you for quickly reply